# opencart how to make price range filter

Tags: php, opencart

I have filter data. How I can made filter by price range? All products from $5 until $10 for expample!

```
 $filter_data = array(
        'sort'  => 'p.price',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'start' => 0,
        'limit' => 1
 );
```

Comment: You may have a look at [this](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=23022&filter_search=range) and do something similar

Comment: @SergeyChizhik In this extension author just remove products from frontend... I wanna make range with mysql when I am asking for products... But thanks

Answer (score 0):

just hookup the code in model

e.g)

```
if(isset($data['price']) \\ [5,10]
{
   between $data['price'][0] and $data['price'][1]
 }
```